How to right align \intertext and \shortintertext
Currently shortintertext is left aligned, how to make it right aligned? using \raggedright doesnt work
MWE
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, mathtools}
\usepackage{derivative} % Derivative

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\yesnumber{\incr@eqnum\tag{\theequation}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}\label{eq:1.1-y}
  & 
  y
  = \frac{c_0}{\varphi(x)}
  + \frac{1  }{\varphi(x)}
  \,\int{\left(\frac{1}{4}\,x^3\right)\,\varphi(x)\,\odif{x}}
  %
  %
  %
  = 
  & \\[3ex] \shortintertext{\raggedright Using \eqref{eq:1.1-phi_x}} & 
  % & \text{Using \eqref{eq:1.1-phi_x}} \\& 
  = \frac{c_0}{\left(c_1\,e^{x^2/8}\right)}
  + \frac{1  }{\left(c_1\,e^{x^2/8}\right)}
  \,\int{\left(\frac{1}{4}\,x^3\right)\,\left(c_1\,e^{x^2/8}\right)\,\odif{x}}
  = &\\& 
  = \frac{c_0}{\left(c_1\,e^{x^2/8}\right)}
  + \frac{1  }{e^{x^2/8}}
  \,\int{\left(\frac{1}{4}\,x^3\right)\,\left(e^{x^2/8}\right)\,\odif{x}}
  = &\\& 
  & \\ \shortintertext{\raggedright Using \eqref{eq:1.1-prim}} & 
  = c_2\,e^{-x^2/8}
  + \frac{1}{e^{x^2/8}}
  \,\left(
    \left(x^2-8\right)\,e^{x^2/8}
  \right)
  = &\\& 
  \yesnumber
  = c_2\,e^{-x^2/8}
  + x^2-8
  = &\\& 
  & \\ \shortintertext{\raggedright Using \eqref{eq:1.1-c_2}} & 
  = 4\,e^{-x^2/8} + x^2 - 8
  % 
  % 
  % 
  &\\[3ex]& 
  c_2 = c_0/c_1
  & 
\end{flalign*}
% solving y(0) = -4
\begin{flalign*}\label{eq:1.1-c_2}
  &
  & \\ \shortintertext{\raggedright Using \eqref{eq:1.1-y}} & 
  \yesnumber
  y(0)
  = c_2\,e^{-0^2/8}+ 0^2 - 8
  = c_2 - 8
  = - 4
  \implies c_2 = 4
  &
\end{flalign*}
% φ(x)
\begin{flalign} \label{eq:1.1-phi_x}
  & 
  \varphi(x) 
  = \exp{\left(
    \int{\frac{1}{4}\,x\,\odif{x}}
  \right)}
  = \exp{\left(
    \frac{1}{4} \left( \frac{x^2}{2} + c \right)
  \right)}
  = \exp{\left( \frac{c}{4} \right)}
  \,\exp{\left(
    \frac{x^2}{8}
  \right)}
  % \notag
  % = &\\&
  = c_1\,e^{ \frac{x^2}{8} }
  ; &\\& \notag
  c_1 = e^{c/4}
  & 
\end{flalign}
% prim
\begin{flalign*}\label{eq:1.1-prim}
  & 
  P\left(
    \left(\frac{1}{4}\,x^3\right)\,\left(e^{x^2/8}\right)
  \right)
  = 
  P\left(
    \left( x^2 \right)
    \,\left(
      e^{x^2/8}
      \,\frac{x}{4}
    \right)
  \right)
  = 
  P\left(
    \left( x^2 \right) % u
    \,\left( e^{x^2/8} \right)' % v'
  \right)
  = &\\&
  = 
  % u\,v
  x^2\,P\left(
    \left( e^{x^2/8} \right)'
  \right)
  % P(v\,u')
  - P\left(
    P\left(
      \odv{}{x}\left( e^{x^2/8} \right)
    \right)
    \,\odv{x^2}{x}
  \right)
  = &\\&
  = 
  x^2\,e^{x^2/8} 
  - P\left(
    e^{x^2/8}
    \,2\,x
  \right)
  = 
  x^2\,e^{x^2/8} 
  - 8
  \,P\left(
    e^{x^2/8}
    \,x/4
  \right)
  = &\\&
  = 
  \left(x^2-8\right)
  \,e^{x^2/8} 
  \yesnumber
  & 
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}



\raggedright (having a non-justified right side of the text) is not what you're looking for. Use \raggedleft (will push content to the right so the left side is ragged).

A bigger question: Why do you want to have document elements (both in math and regular text) be flush right?

\int does not take a formal argument. The only thing that writing \int{...} achieves is to create code clutter.

Ah i see, Werner, thanks for explaining never the less having \hfill before the text does the trick
Also i just want to justify the small intertext saying using x.y to the right, for the math i want as is displayed in the mwe, i just wanted an easier way to write since the way i found out was using &\\& for pagebreaks which was a workaround

Mico, having those \int{...} does create more characters and clutter, but helps me a lot when im solving large equations. thats why i use it

@Werner for the alignment i found out that one can add the option fleqn to amsmath and it would make it all to the right, i found that out thanks to a comment you posted on another question, although, i want some equations to be centered, what can i do to achieve that?

@Felipe9: If you want a mixture of alignments, then don't set anything as a package option (otherwise it affects things globally). Instead, for centered content use align or gather, and for a full length equation, use flalign.

That i wished but flalign centers the equations as well, here's an example:
  \begin{flalign*}
    (D-2)\,x + (D^2 + 3\,D)\,y = t + 1
    \\ \begin{pmatrix}
      (5\,D^2 - 12\,D + 4)\,x 
      \\ + (5\,D^3 + 13\,D^2 - 7\,D - 3)\,y
    \end{pmatrix}
  \end{flalign*}


You can define a right-aligned \shortintertext in the preamble by
\newcommand{\Rshortintertext}[1]{\shortintertext{\hfill #1}}

and use it whenever you want to right-align your intertext.


That solves half my question, thanks
